# How to have two separate onClick events with one element inside another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a `<div>` element inside another `<div>`.  I have an onClick event on the containing div but I want the inside div to ignore that onClick event, because I have a separate onClick event going on in that one.  Here's some example code:

```
<div id='container' onClick='javascript:function1();'>
  outside of the inside div
  <div id='inside' onClick='javascript:function2();'>
    inside the inside div
  </div>
</div>
```

Just imagine the container is one big box, and the inside div is a smaller box inside of it.  Basically the way the code works now, is every time I click "inside", it fires both the onClick even for "container" and "inside".  I don't want that; I want each to have their own onClick event.  Is this possible?

Comment: This link can be useful: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside `function2()` put `return false` which will prevent event bubling.

Since you have mentioned jquery in your tag you can remove the event handler from the HTML markup and put it inside document.ready

HTML

```
<div id='container'>
  outside of the inside div
  <div id='inside'>
    inside the inside div
  </div>
</div>
```

jQUery

```
$(function(){
    $("#container").click(function(){
        function1();
    });

    $("#inside").click(function(){
        function2();
        return false;
    });    
});
```

You can also use [**`event.stopPropagation()`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) instead of return false.